# Moving a rectangle in Python

Tags: python, pygame

So, I have a rectangle in Pygame and it moves randomly and diagonally. How can I make it move only left, right, forward or backward. Also, when it meets an obstacle, it should rotate 90 degrees and change the direction. Here's the code I have:

```
# Main program loop
  while not done:

# Loop through any window events
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # The user clicked 'close' or hit Alt-F4
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

    # The user clicked the mouse button
    # or pressed a key
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        # Is the ball not moving?
        if ball.change_y == 0:

            # Start in the middle of the screen at a random y location
            ball.rect.x = screen_width/2
            ball.rect.y = random.randrange(10, screen_height - 0)

            # Set a random vector
            ball.change_y = random.randrange(-5, 6)
            ball.change_x =  random.randrange(5, 10)

            # Is the ball headed left or right? Select randomly
            if( random.randrange(2) == 0 ):
                ball.change_x *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the [transform](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) module to make the rect rotate. For example, `pygame.transform.rotate(ball.rect,90)`. As for moving, you need to change the values of `ball.rect.x` and `ball.rect.y`. An example of this is:

```
if ball_moving_up:
    ball.rect.y += 5 #The smaller the increment the smoother it will appear
if ball_moving_down:
    ball.rect.y -= 5
if ball_moving_right:
    ball.rect.x += 5
if ball_moving_left:
    ball.rect.x -= 5
```

Also you are going to want to update the background after each increment otherwise your rect will appear as a solid line.

Comment if you have any questions.
Hope this helped.

Comment: It depends on what you want. You are going to want to put it in the game loop somewhere. If the user is controlling it with the arrow keys you would put it in the `pygame.keydown` if statement and change the `if ball_moving_up/down/right/left` to `if pygame.key == K_RIGHT/K_LEFT/K_DOWN/K_UP`.